# Filter results depending on arg

Tags: django, filter, django-templates, filtering

In my project management app I have a page that lists all the projects in the db. I want it to be possible to filter the projects, so that for example only the projects where the user is an admin is shown. The code in the template below calls the project_list view with different args depending on what the user clicked on.

What I need help with is the queries the arrows in the view below points at, i.e. for only showing projects where the user is a member and all the projects where the user is neither an admin or a member.

**the template:**

```
<h5>Show only projects where you are:</h5>
<div id="filter_div">
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url project_list 'admin' %}">Admin</a>
    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{% url project_list 'member' %}">Member</a>
    <a class="btn" href="{% url project_list 'not_member' %}">Not member</a>
</div>
```

**the view:**

```
def project_list(request, projects_to_show='All'):
    if projects_to_show == 'admin':
        projects = get_list_or_404(Project.objects.filter(added_by_user = user))
    else:
        if projects_to_show == 'member':
            projects = get_list_or_404(?) // <- only projects where user is a member
        else:
            if projects_to_show == 'not_member' :
                projects = get_list_or_404(?) // <----- only projects where user is NOT admin OR member

        projects = get_list_or_404(Project.objects.order_by('name')) // <- all projects (works)

    return render(request, 'projects/list.html', {"projects" : projects, "headline" : "All projects"})
```

The model 'Project' and 'User' has a many-to-many relationship (i.e the table project_users exists in the db). This is the project model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ... the rest of the fields...   
    added_by_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='projects')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORRECTED BELOW: the filters should be set like so ... (I changed the text accordingly)

```
users__id__iexact=user.id
```

The query for `projects_to_show == 'member'` should be something like:

```
projects = Projects.objects.filter(users__id__iexact=user.id)
```

Thinking about the last one, `projects_to_show == 'not_member'` I think this might work:

```
projects = Projects.objects.exclude(users__id__iexact=user.id)
```

To exclude both users and added_by_user, just add an extra exclude. E.g:

```
projects = Projects.objects.exclude(users__id__iexact=user.id)
projects = projects.exclude(added_by_user=user)
```

Or as one statement, this should work:

```
projects = Projects.objects.exclude(users__id__iexact=user, added_by_user=user)
```

The filter is a field lookup. [The django details.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iexact)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The last one - will that exclude both projects where user is an admin or a member?

Comment: Try this: `projects = Projects.objects.exclude(users__iexact=user, added_by_user__iexact=user)`. You could also simply filter projects: `projects.exclude(added_by_user__iexact=user)`. Probably don't need to use `added_by_user__iexact=user`, because that expression simplifies to `added_by_user=user`, eg. `projects.exclude(added_by_user=user)`

Comment: The filter you're talking about, projects.exclude(added_by_user__iexact=user), how can I use it?

Comment: Thanks. Though, this is thrown:
"Related Field has invalid lookup: iexact" :/

Comment: Here it is: http://pastie.org/private/av7u0gqfi9fipqlvws481g (exact works but not iexact)

Comment: The problem was a little tricker, but is resolved rather simple. See the above update and code refresh